# How to replace current index.html body content with another html file with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working simple blog code example with 3 nav-buttons Home/All posts/About me/ which changes markdown story to html. The code looks like this:

```html
<div class="container-md">
  <img src="assets/ico/android-chrome-192x192.png" class="rounded float-left" alt="..." height="42" width="42">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-end">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="//test.net">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="allPosts" onclick="allStories()" href="#">All posts</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container-sm">
  <zero-md src="stories/how-to-install-aws-bucket-software-centos7.md"></zero-md>
</div>
```

```js
function allStories() {
  console.log("Works")
  $("#allPosts").load("pages/allstories.html");
}
```

Right now if I click on nav-button - All posts  - it adds the content from

> pages/allstories.html

on a button area. But my goal is to replace the

```
<zero-md src="stories/how-to-install-aws-bucket-software-centos7.md"></zero-md>
```

content with new allstories.html content. How can I achieve that?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Change `$("#allPosts")` to `$('.container-sm')`

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it works. Now I get it. The question remains if I want to replace only that particular content <zero-md src="stories/how-to-install-aws-bucket-software-centos7.md"></zero-md> not all container-sm class?

Comment: If there are multiple then you need to make the selector more specific, either by including parent elements in the selector, or placing a unique `id` on the specific element you want to target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give id for both container-sm and zero-md division then try like this `function allStories(){
   $(#zero-md).hide();
   $(#container1).load("pages/allstories.html");
   }`